# Driver issue with PostgreSQL/Clojure

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, clojure

I am attempting to access a Postgres database inside of Clojure. I've found a ton of examples of projects using DBs, setting up the database like this:

```
(def db
    {:classname "org.postgresql.Driver"
     :subprotocol "postgresql"
     :subname "//localhost/testdb"
     :username "postgres"
     :password "postgres"})
```

I'm then trying to then access the database like this:

```
(sql/with-connection db
    (sql/with-query-results recs ["select * from asdf"]
        (doseq [rec recs]
            (println rec))))
```

However, I'm getting this error:

```
No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost/testdb
  [Thrown class java.sql.SQLException]
```

I'm assuming the problem is with `:classname "org.postgresql.Driver"`, but I'm not sure what the solution is. I imagine I need to provide this driver, but I'm not sure where to get it or where to put it. There is a download available at [postgresql.org](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html) - should I download that? Or is there something I can put in my project settings to get `lein` to download it as a dependency? Once I have it, where does it go?

---

**Edit** (in response to @mtnygard):
I have this in my project.clj:

```
(defproject hello-www "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
    :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.2.1"]
                   [postgresql/postgresql "8.4-702.jdbc4"]
                   ...]
```

My postgres version is 8.4:

```
[/media/data/dev/clojure/hello-www (postgres *)]$ postgres --version
postgres (PostgreSQL) 8.4.8
```

Comment: Did you run "lein deps" after adding postgresql to your project.clj?

Comment: Also, how are you executing the main body of your project? "lein deps" just puts the jars in lib/. You still have to run your program with a configured classpath. "lein run" and "lein repl" will both set up your classpath, for example.

Comment: You found the problem! I had run `lein deps`, but I had not updated my REPL. Restarting swank gave me a connection. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are on the right track. The exception indicates that your classpath doesn't have org.postgresql.Driver anywhere.

Checking jarvana.com, I find [this entry](http://jarvana.com/jarvana/inspect-pom/postgresql/postgresql/9.0-801.jdbc4/postgresql-9.0-801.jdbc4.pom) for a postgres JDBC 4 driver. There are other versions available, depending on the rest of your runtime environment. You can include this by editing your project.clj file to add this dependency:

```
(defproject xxxxxxx
  ;;; other stuff

  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.2.0"]
                 [postgresql/postgresql "9.0-801.jdbc4"]]
 )
```

Comment: I already have postgresql in my project.clj - please see my updated answer.

Comment: For anyone with the same problem- make sure the above is in project.clj. Then, run `lein deps`. You may have to restart your REPL if you're in one to make sure it gets the update.